# Does Faster R-CNN use sliding window to propose regions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've read the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497) presenting Faster R-CNN but I'm not sure if the region proposals are done by a sliding window.

The part that made me think that it is indeed a normal sliding window is this figure: [Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iALEm.png)

If yes, isn't it a bad way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well the figure does indeed say a sliding window. But there is a catch, this sliding window is actually implemented as a convolution, so it can be efficiently implemented as convolution is a highly optimized operation (and the rest of the network has many convolutional layers).

So its not bad per se. The size of the feature maps where the proposals are generated is around 7x7 (Depending on the used network), but the number of channels is quite large. That can be a bigger performance concern.